# Writing coil (bit) to Modbus PLC

Tags: ios, c, swift4, modbus

I’m having a problem writing to a Schneider Modicon M221 PLC.
I’m using a [Swift wrapper](https://github.com/ktsakaguchi/SwiftLibModbus) around the [LibModbus](http://libmodbus.org) Library (in C).
I can **read** bits and registers no problem - just can’t seem to **write** to them - although I’m getting a “success” response from the device.

It’s as simple as writing “true” to bit 0 using function 05.

Swift(4) call:

```
@objc func writeToPLC() {

    swiftLibModbus.writeBit(address: 0, status: true,
                            success: {
                                    print("writeBit Success")

    },
                            failure: { (error:NSError) in
                                print("Error in WriteBit")

    })

}
```

Which writes to this function in the Swift/ObjC SwiftLibModbus wrapper:

```
func writeBit(address: Int32, status: Bool, success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {
    modbusQueue?.async {
        if modbus_write_bit(self.mb!, address, status ? 1 : 0) >= 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                success()
            }
        } else {
            let error = self.buildNSError(errno: errno)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That writes to these C functions in the library:

```
int modbus_write_bit(modbus_t *ctx, int addr, int status){
return write_single(ctx, _FC_WRITE_SINGLE_COIL, addr,
                    status ? 0xFF00 : 0);
}
```

then:

```
static int write_single(modbus_t *ctx, int function, int addr, int value){
int rc;
int req_length;
uint8_t req[_MIN_REQ_LENGTH];

req_length = ctx->backend->build_request_basis(ctx, function, addr, value, req);

rc = send_msg(ctx, req, req_length);
if (rc > 0) {
    /* Used by write_bit and write_register */
    uint8_t rsp[_MIN_REQ_LENGTH];
    //printf("Print %s, %s, %d ", req, rsp, rc);
    rc = _modbus_receive_msg(ctx, rsp, MSG_CONFIRMATION);
    if (rc == -1)
        return -1;

    rc = check_confirmation(ctx, req, rsp, rc);

}

return rc;}
```

The _FC_WRITE_SINGLE_COIL constant is 0x05
The _MIN_REQ_LENGTH constant is 12

I get "writeBit Success" in the console when running, but the bit status remains the same.

Beginning to wonder if it’s something proprietary with Schneider.

Anyone else had experience in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found out what I was doing wrong. I didn't have the Unit ID set properly. It was at "1" when it should have been "255".

Here's a screenshot of the setting in SoMachine in case anyone else finds themselves in the same situation:

[image]